# Store loaded, grid rendered with rows but no data shown

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here's a grid:

```
Ext.define('Customer_Portal_UI.view.BulkUpdateResultWindow.ResultGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.ResultGrid',
    itemId: 'ResultGrid',
    columns: [
        { text: 'Participant', mapping: 'firstname' },
        { text: 'Success', mapping: 'success' },
        { text: 'Status', mapping: 'statusMessage' }
    ],
    viewConfig: { itemId: 'ResultGridView' },
    initComponent: function () {
        this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            storeId: 'ResultGridStore',
            idProperty: 'contactid',
            fields: [
                'firstname',
                'success',
                'statusMessage',
               'contactid'
            ]
        });

        this.callParent();

    }
});
```

Here's how I attempt do load it:

```
var grid = this.Utils.getCmp('gridpanel[itemId=ResultGrid]');
var store = grid.getStore();
var response = Ext.JSON.decode(result.responseText);

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    store.add({ firstname: response[i].contact.firstname, success: response[i].success, statusMessage: response[i].statusMessage, contactid: response[i].contact.contactid });
}
```

If I go in the console after that for loop, the store is loaded. If I call `getStore()` on the grid, its store contains data as well.

But the grid is rendered with the right number of lines (matching # of records in response) but those lines are empty.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column doesn't have a `mapping` property. Use `dataIndex`.

Comment: Wow. This was a *bad* day. I've got half a dozens of grids in my app and could not spot that. Thanks.